# With XmlSerializer, how to set element names for a List?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I can't seem to get the XmlSerializer attributes to work. I have

```
public class DriveData
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int SizeGB { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsOK { get; set; }
}
```

```
static List<DriveData> DiskDrives { get; set; }
```

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DriveData>));
FileStream xmlFile = File.Create("DiskDrives.xml");
serializer.Serialize(xmlFile, DiskDrives);
xmlFile.Close();
```

What I want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HardDrives>
    <HardDrive>
        <Model>Seagate1</Model>
        ...
</HardDrive>
<HardDrive>
    ...
</HardDrive>
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfDriveData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DriveData>
    <Model>Seagate1</Model>
    <Type>SATA</Type>
    <SizeGB>999</SizeGB>
    ...
  </DriveData>
  <DriveData>
    ...
  </DriveData>
</ArrayOfDriveData>
```

`[XmlElement(ElementName = "HardDrives")]` on my `List<DriveData>` does nothing. `[XmlElement(ElementName = "HardDrive")]` on my `DriveData` class causes a build error. How do I set the root and the `<HardDrive>` elements names to what I want?

Comment: Google XML Serializer Attributes, you'll apply an attribute to your properties and specify a name in that attribute. Specifically Array and ArrayItem.

Comment: Your sample XML is not clear. Do you want to have a single parent called `<HardDrives>`, and multiple `<HardDrive>` children of it?

Comment: Yes. My app retrieves data on the hard drives on a computer. The root 'HardDrives' element will contain one or more 'HardDrive' elements, depending on the system it is run on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your model. Use XmlType attribute for the class and second argument as new XmlRootAttribute("HardDrives") while creating serializer object.

```
[XmlType("HardDrive")]
public class DriveData
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int SizeGB { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsOK { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static List<DriveData> DiskDrives  { get; set; } = new List<DriveData>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DiskDrives.Add(new DriveData { Model = "Seagate1", Type = "SATA", SizeGB = 999 });
        DiskDrives.Add(new DriveData { Model = "Seagate2", Type = "SATA", SizeGB = 777 });

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DriveData>), new XmlRootAttribute("HardDrives"));
        FileStream xmlFile = File.Create("DiskDrives.xml");

        serializer.Serialize(xmlFile, DiskDrives);
        xmlFile.Close();

        Console.Read();
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the `XmlSerializer` *can* serialize a `List<T>` directly, like you do with `new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DriveData>))`, the trade-off is you can't do much regarding the names of elements produced. A better way is to wrap the list into a class that will be attributed like this:

```
[XmlRoot("HardDrives")]
public class DiskDrives
{
    [XmlElement("HardDrive")]
    public List<DriveData> Drives { get; set; }
}
```

The `[XmlRoot]` attribute denotes the top-level document element, while the `[XmlElement]` attribute controls how the property is serialized.

The XML produced by the `XmlSerializer` will then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<HardDrives xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <HardDrive>
    <Model>WD</Model>
    …
  </HardDrive>
  <HardDrive>
    <Model>Seagate</Model>
    …
  </HardDrive>
</HardDrives>
```

In case you'd embed the `List<DriveData>` into a more complex structure, the alternate approach is to use `[XmlArray]` and `[XmlArrayItem]` attributes, which control how an `IEnumerable` property is serialized and what elements name is applied to its items. The following data structure:

```
[XmlRoot("Inventory")]
public class Inventory
{
    … more properties here…

    [XmlArray("HardDrives")]
    [XmlArrayItem("HardDrive")]
    public List<DriveData> Drives { get; set; }
}
```

would then yield an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Inventory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  … more properties would be serialized here …
  <HardDrives>
    <HardDrive>
      <Model>WD</Model>
      …
    </HardDrive>
    <HardDrive>
      <Model>Seagate</Model>
      …
    </HardDrive>
  </HardDrives>
</Inventory>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be much more better ways to achieve this but here is another approach.

```
private static void GenerateXml()
{
        List<DriveData> DiskDrives = new List<DriveData>();
        DiskDrives.Add(new DriveData() { Model = "model1", Type = "type1", SizeGB = 10, SerialNumber = "20155", IsOK = false });
        DiskDrives.Add(new DriveData() { Model = "model2", Type = "type2", SizeGB = 20, SerialNumber = "20165", IsOK = true });

        var newDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", null, "yes"));
        XElement xmlElements = new XElement("HardDrives",
            from item in DiskDrives
            select new XElement("HardDrive",
                new XElement("Model", item.Model),
                new XElement("Type", item.Type),
                new XElement("SizeGB", item.SizeGB),
                new XElement("SerialNumber", item.SerialNumber),
                new XElement("IsOK", item.IsOK)));
        newDoc.Add(xmlElements);
        newDoc.Save(@"C:\sample.xml");
}
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<HardDrives>
  <HardDrive>
    <Model>model1</Model>
    <Type>type1</Type>
    <SizeGB>10</SizeGB>
    <SerialNumber>20155</SerialNumber>
    <IsOK>false</IsOK>
  </HardDrive>
  <HardDrive>
    <Model>model2</Model>
    <Type>type2</Type>
    <SizeGB>20</SizeGB>
    <SerialNumber>20165</SerialNumber>
    <IsOK>true</IsOK>
  </HardDrive>
</HardDrives>
```